# definition has no INLINE/INLINABLE pragma

Tags: haskell, inlining

I'm trying to do specialization of a method used in a tight inner loop but GHC complains about the following:

```
src/Mac/CoreGraphics/Image.hs:140:1: Warning:
    You cannot SPECIALISE `toRealFrac'
      because its definition has no INLINE/INLINABLE pragma
      (or its defining module `Data.Image.Pixel' was compiled without -O)

src/Mac/CoreGraphics/Image.hs:140:1: Warning:
    Ignoring useless SPECIALISE pragma for class method selector `toRealFrac'
```

However, it is clearly being built with -O:

```
/usr/local/bin/ghc --make -no-link -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -static -outputdir dist/build/imagesorter-hs/imagesorter-hs-tmp -odir dist/build/imagesorter-hs/imagesorter-hs-tmp -hidir dist/build/imagesorter-hs/imagesorter-hs-tmp -stubdir dist/build/imagesorter-hs/imagesorter-hs-tmp -i -idist/build/imagesorter-hs/imagesorter-hs-tmp -isrc -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/imagesorter-hs/imagesorter-hs-tmp -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -hide-all-packages -package-db dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id base-4.6.0.1-6c351d70a24d3e96f315cba68f3acf57 -XHaskell2010 src/ImageSorter.hs
```

And clearly, I do have the INLINABLE pragma:

```
instance PixelComponent Word8 where
  minValue = minBound
  maxValue = maxBound
  toRealFrac c = fromIntegral c / fromIntegral (maxValue :: Word8)
  {-# INLINABLE toRealFrac #-}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think it's not possible to mark as INLINABLE instance methods, it has to be specified in the type class. `GHC-7.8` will offer a specific pragma for it: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc1/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#specialize-instance-pragma

Comment: Where are you trying to `SPECIALIZE`? I need to see more code.

Comment: @DannyNavarro Your link is about *specializing* instances, not inlining them. But you can also specialize the entire instance with a single pragma [pre-7.8](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#specialize-instance-pragma). You can also specialize or inline individual functions in an instance, none of which requires a class pragma.

Comment: @Eric, sorry I meant `SPECIALIZE` instead of `INLINABLE`. I didn't know it was possible to *specialize* instance methods. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: OP, I'm interested in this question. I hope you'll give us some more information so we can find out what is causing your problem...

Comment: I never solved the problem, unfortunately :(